# When I use \animate in beamer, how do I move back in my presentation?

Tags: beamer, animations

Matthew Leingang just provided a [nice example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6330/animating-protocols/6331#6331) of beamer's `\animate` method. If in this example (don't want to repeat it here) I replace `\animate<2-10>` with `\animate<3-10>`, how will I then be able to move back from the last page to the *second* page? (Moving to the first page is easy ...) I tried the navigation symbols, but to no avail.

Comment: I think that you need to add a link in order to do that...then in the presentation you will have to click on the link. it has to be a special link not just a move back, but rather a "move to a particular slide" link...but I'll leave writing a full answer to somebody else.

Comment: One thing that doesn't work is trying to hit the left arrow eight times quickly.  I tried that!  Hyperlinks are covered in Section 10.1 of the beamer manual.

Comment: @Matthew: I tried the hitting 8x thing too `:-(`. What I'd really like is to make "page up" work somehow!

Comment: it would be very nice to be able to connect pgup with a hyperlink (I am 100% sure the hyperlink option is available...but is requires using the mouse)

Comment: @Yossi Farjoun: that sounds like a PDF-viewer-specific implementation, and outside of the PDF file format spec.

Comment: I'm now having the same problem and really would like to know how it can be done.

Comment: @Hendrik: You are welcome. I need this as well and I also wanted to try out a bounty anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It starts with an empty frame. Clicking the mouse button views the presentation,
clicking again starts it, but not if you click into the frame of the object (look at the mouse pointer!). At the end of the presentation you can click into the object and will go back to the second frame.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\hypertarget<2>{2nd}{}
\hyperlink<2-10>{2nd}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}]
\node (s) {sender};
\node (r) at (5,0) {receiver};
\animate<3-10>
\foreach \pos in {0.1,0.2,...,1.0} {
  \action<+>{
    \path (s) -- (r) node[pos=\pos,coordinate] (p) {};
    \draw[->] (s) -- (p);
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Herbert: Thanks for this answer. I can't get it to work right now, but this is a viewer problem. I'll test it tomorrow on a different computer.

Comment: @Hendrik: it works only eith the adobe reader

Comment: @Herbert: Thanks. Well, I used that, but even Matthew's example didn't animate. No idea what's wrong with my computer.

Comment: @Herbert: Make sure you do it in fullscreen mode.

Comment: @Martin: sure, how could I have seen it, when not already done so ;-)

Comment: Sorry, Herbert, it was meant for @Hendrik or course. I got confused with the `He`s in both of your names :-)

Comment: @Martin: Thanks, I indeed forgot to switch to fullscreen mode, stupid me. @Herbert: Your solution doesn't meet my request to move back from the last page to the _second_ page, but I was able to achieve that myself, based on your answer. I'll take the liberty and edit your answer accordingly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Hendrik: Works fine for me as well. I will give the bounty after you tick the answer, or is this supposed to be other way around?

Comment: @Martin: It's independent, I think. I'll wait a few hours before accepting. You can go ahead.