# How to use preview and animate packages together?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, preview, animate

I'm used to prepare tikz graphics with `preview` or `standalone` packages to crop them. Now I've started to experiment with animations and wanted to do the same. My first test was with [Alexander Grahn's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6330/animating-protocols/6394#6394) to [Animating Protocols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6330/1952), but as soon as I include

```
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
```

in its preamble, pdflatex complains with

```
! Package animate Error: Contents of first frame must not have zero width.
```

I've found some examples prepared with `preview` but all of them use `\animategraphics` 
command instead of `animateinline` environment with `\multiframe` command.

So my first question is, has any sense to do what I want? It is producing an animated clipped graphic to be included in another file. "No, it hasn't" can be a good answer but if it has, what am I doing wrong?

Here you have the code to test it. I've also tested adding a `\usebaoundingbox` but without any succes.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{animateinline}[loop]{10}
  \multiframe{10}{rPos=0.1+0.1}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}]
     %\useasboundingbox (-2,-2) rectangle (7,2);
     \node (s) {sender};
     \node (r) at (5,0) {receiver};
     \path (s) -- (r) node[pos=\rPos,coordinate] (p) {};
     \draw[->] (s) -- (p);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\end{animateinline}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you tried it with a normal document class? IIRC `beamer` doesn't work nicely with `preview` as well.

Comment: @Ignasi: As Martin said in his answer and his comment to KF Leong, there isn't much point in using `preview` with `animate` other than getting a tightly cropped PDF around the animation. You cannot `\includegraphics` or `\includepdf` it into another document, because the PDF annotations, which provide interactivity, get lost in this process. They have to be re-built in every new PDF document. Therefore `standalone` is probably the better choice.

Comment: @Alexander: I tested preview with animate because I use it with tikz graphics but now I'll try with standalone. By the way, including a newframe (with a tikzpicture) before the multiframe it's also a possible workarround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a solution which uses the `standalone` class. As said, animations will be lost if you include that PDF as image in another document. However, you could just `\input` the file below after loading the `standalone` *package* in the main document.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[loop]{10}
  \multiframe{10}{rPos=0.1+0.1}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}]
     %\useasboundingbox (-2,-2) rectangle (7,2);
     \node (s) {sender};
     \node (r) at (5,0) {receiver};
     \path (s) -- (r) node[pos=\rPos,coordinate] (p) {};
     \draw[->] (s) -- (p);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Martin, for the pointer to the `standalone` class and package (+1). It allows for combining self-contained documents into a main one without (re)moving the preambles, right?

Comment: @Alex: Yes, exactly. It can also copy the sub-preambles to the main one if the `subpreambles` option is used with the package. This requires one additional compiler run.

Comment: *Neither* `xelatex` *nor* `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` can compile it. `ps2pdf` produced error message: `Error: /undefined in pgfo
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1910   1   3   %oparray_pop   1909   1   3   %oparray_pop   1893` to be continued...

Comment: [This code](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25063/what-kind-of-magic-does-preview-package-do-to-produce-a-tight-paper-size/25080#25080) also does not work with PSTricks and `animate`.

Comment: @xport: Try the new v1.0 of `standalone` which is much better for XeLaTeX.

Comment: Compiling your code with either `xelatex` or `pdflatex` and then compressing the resulting PDF with ghostscript (gswin64c -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf) will make the animation failed.

Comment: @DamienWalters: Looks like Ghostscript removes the animation part. I don't think you can do much about that from the LaTeX side.

Comment: `latex` followed by `dvips` followed by `gswin64c -r10000 -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -dAutoRotatePages=/None -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.ps` does not need compression and the animation still works as expected.

Comment: @DamienWalters: Sorry, is this meant as information only, or are you asking me for help?

Comment: It is just for information that animation no longer works when I compile your code with either xelatex or pdflatex followed by a compression with ghostscript. But it is not the case when I compile with a combo sequence latex-dvips-ghostscript. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Change the `\PreviewEnvironment` option to `animateinline`.

Comment: Indeed, changing `\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}` to `\PreviewEnvironment{animateinline}` does it. It also works with a different class as `beamer`, but you will get other fonts by default. Note that the animation will be lost if you include that PDF as image in another document.