# What kind of "magic" does preview package do to produce a tight paper size?

Tags: pstricks, paper-size, preview, dvips, standalone

Actually the following method, that looks like reinventing the wheel, has been discarded once I have known the existence of `preview` package.

```
% WithoutPreview.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\newcommand\All{0.1}
\newcommand\Left{-\All}
\newcommand\Right{\All}
\newcommand\Bottom{-\All}
\newcommand\Top{\All}


%%%%%%%%%%%% BEGIN SETTINGS %%%%%%%%%%%%
\headheight=0pt
\headsep=0pt
\parindent=0pt
\topskip=0pt

\topmargin=-72.27pt
\oddsidemargin=-72.27pt
\paperwidth=\dimexpr\Right\psxunit-\Left\psxunit\relax
\paperheight=\dimexpr\Top\psyunit-\Bottom\psyunit\relax

\special{papersize=\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight}
\pagestyle{empty}
%%%%%%%%%%%%% END SETTINGS %%%%%%%%%$%%%



\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(\Left,\Bottom)(\Right,\Top)
\psframe[linewidth=0.01](\Left,\Bottom)(\Right,\Top)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The idea in `WithoutPreview.tex` is to produce a single output with a tight paper size.

Using the following batch file,

```
rem batch.bat takes an input file name WITHOUT extension.
latex %1
dvips -D10000 -t unknown %1
gswin32c -r10000 -dAutoRotatePages=/None -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=%1.pdf %1.ps
```

I get the following output that is not tight enough.

[image]

> Note: There are random white spaces at the edges. Their exact position
>   cannot be predicted. They are sometimes on the left and top edges,
>   sometimes on the left and bottom edges, etc. They depend on the
>   specified settings.

Once I have known the existence of `preview` package and played with it, I discarded the method I used in `WithoutPreview.tex`.

The following code use `preview` package,

```
% WithPreview.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\newcommand\All{0.1}
\newcommand\Left{-\All}
\newcommand\Right{\All}
\newcommand\Bottom{-\All}
\newcommand\Top{\All}

%%%%%%%%%%%% BEGIN SETTINGS %%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=0pt
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}
%%%%%%%%%%%%% END SETTINGS %%%%%%%%%$%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(\Left,\Bottom)(\Right,\Top)
\psframe[linewidth=0.01](\Left,\Bottom)(\Right,\Top)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

and when compiled with the same batch file, `batch.bat`, it produces a tight output as follows.

[image]

> Note: The random white spaces have gone!

The bad news came yesterday as I cannot use `preview` package together with PSTricks related packages and `animate` package.

### Questions

Does `preview` invoke `pdfcrop` behind the scene? If `preview` does not invoke `pdfcrop`, what kind of magic does it do to produce a tight paper size? I am interested in extracting the fragment codes, that is used in `preview` to produce a tight paper size, and insert them into my `WithoutPreview.tex`.

Note: `xelatex` can give better output than `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` does, but `xelatex` runs too slowly.

Another note: `preview` package  ignores `\pagecolor{<non-white color>}` declared in the preamble. However, it is not a big issue as the non-white background can be obtained by a PSTricks' `psframe*[linecolor=<non-white>](...,...)(...,...)`.

Comment: Have a look at the new `crop` option of `standalone` v1.0. I implemented some boxing and page resizing for it which should be of interest for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

preview does not invoke pdfcrop. Here is the relevant code from preview inserted into your example. As you can clearly see it simply takes the tex box size in sp and converts that into the postscript page size using the relevant conversion factor (65781.76):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\newcommand\All{0.1}
\newcommand\Left{-\All}
\newcommand\Right{\All}
\newcommand\Bottom{-\All}
\newcommand\Top{\All}

\makeatletter
\newbox\prv

\begin{document}
    \setbox\prv\vbox{\noindent
       \begin{pspicture}(\Left,\Bottom)(\Right,\Top)
        \psframe[linewidth=0.01](\Left,\Bottom)(\Right,\Top)
        \end{pspicture}
    \par\unskip\setbox0\lastbox
    \nointerlineskip\hbox{\unhbox0}%
    }
   \voffset=-\ht\prv
   \hoffset=0pt\relax
   \shipout\vbox{%
      \@begindvi
      \special{!userdict begin/preview-bop-level 0 def%
      /eop-hook{/preview-bop-level dup load dup 0 gt{1 sub}if store}bind def
      /bop-hook{preview-bop-level 0 le{7{currentfile token not{stop}if
       65781.76 div DVImag mul}repeat 72 add 72 2 copy gt{exch}if 4 2 roll
       neg 2 copy lt{exch}if dup 0 gt{pop 0 exch}
      {exch dup 0 lt{pop 0}if}ifelse 720 add exch 720 add 3 1 roll
      4{5 -1 roll add 4 1 roll}repeat
      <</PageSize[5 -1 roll 6 index sub 5 -1 roll 5 index sub]%
       /PageOffset[7 -2 roll [1 1 dtransform exch]%
       {0 ge{neg}if exch}forall]>>setpagedevice}if%
      /preview-bop-level dup load dup 0 le{/isls false def%
          /vsize 792 def/hsize 612 def}if 1 add store}bind def end}
     \special{ps::0 0 0 0
     \number\ht\prv \space\number\dp\prv \space\number\wd\prv \space}
     \box\prv
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have tested it for some scenario and it works in the same way the `preview` package works. It also fails to work with PSTricks and `animate` package. However, I am satisfied with this answer. :-)