# Environment not working inside \multido using standalone document class

Tags: errors, standalone

I have the following code

```
\documentclass[multi={image},crop,ignorerest]{standalone}%
\usepackage{multido}
\begin{document}
\multido{\iframe=1+1}{2}{
\begin{image}
\iframe
\end{image}
}
\end{document}
```

which is failing with this error:

```
ERROR: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.

--- TeX said ---
\endsa@boxit ...dvarwidth \color@endgroup \egroup 

l.8 }
```

Can you help me figure out what is happening?

Comment: Related [question about multiple frames / animation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24947/how-to-use-preview-and-animate-packages-together) which accepted answer also uses `standalone`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `ignorerest` which tells `standalone` to ignore *everything* outside the `image` environments. This also includes the `\multido` line, which is not what you want. The rest is ignored by storing it inside a box which is never used. This adds a group around everything after `\begin{document}` and the `\begin{image}`, i.e. the `\multido` line which triggers the error. You need to simply remove the `ignorerest` option. Also add `%` after `\begin{image}` to avoid a space there. Then it works fine for me.

Comment: @MarinScharrer: I removed `ignorerest` and it worked! Thanks

Comment: @Mário: Because `\multido` seems to be used often I now implemented a `multido` option for the `standalone` class which will wrap the content automatically in a `multi` environment and also ensures that `ignorerest` is supported with it. It will be part of the next release.