# Missing endgroup in animation

Tags: tikz-pgf, animate

Where is the missing endgroup in the next code ?

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{calc,animate}

\newcommand{\Cercle}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
    \draw[->,>=stealth] (-.4pt,0) -- (4.5,0) ;
    \foreach \i in {0,...,4} {
        \draw (\i,0) -- (\i,-3pt) node[below] {\i} ; }
    \pgfmathsetmacro\Angle{270-360*#1/3.14159}
    \draw[red] (-.4pt,0) -- (#1,0) arc (270:\Angle:.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[controls,loop]{12}
  \multiframe{10}{nxb=0+.1}{\Cercle{\nxb}}
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{calc,animate}
```

to

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,calc,animate}
```

and your code will work again.

From standalone documentation:

> For pictures drawn with TikZ a dedicated tikz option is provided which
>   loads the tikz package and also configures the tikzpicture environment to
>   create a single cropped page.

`multiframe` or `animateinline` have problem with this `single cropped page` for every `tikzpicture`.

I must admit that I've found it by chance but [I knew](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24959/1952) that `standalone` works with `animateinline`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Tarass: The graph gets squeezed vertically while the animation progresses. A common bounding box is required for all frames of the sequence to avoid this. See the animate manual, page 8.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the proposed solution does not answer the OP's question. Yet hours of study shows that the macro `Cercle` is correct. So this solution uses `multido` skill to tackle the problem and the report is shown below.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{calc,animate,multido}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\newcommand{\Cercle}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
    \draw[->,>=stealth] (-.4pt,0) -- (4.5,0) ;
    \foreach \i in {0,...,4} {
        \draw (\i,0) -- (\i,-3pt) node[below] {\i} ; }
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Angle}{270-360*(#1)/3.14159}
    \draw[red] (-.4pt,0) -- (#1,0) arc (270:\Angle:.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\multido{\rnxb=0+0.1}{40}{
\begin{preview}
\Cercle{\rnxb}
\end{preview}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it produces several pages in a pdf file. How to make an animation with controls with them. I know how make an animated gif. But I need the controls to show off.

Comment: OK, Point to the image and move the wheel on the mouse.

Comment: Thank you. One can avoid animate and multido packages and use foreach instead. I didn't know about preview package.