# How to make travel smoothly a tikz picture across a slide?

Tags: tikz-pgf, animate

The beamer frame below shows a tikz circle. I would like the tikz circle to travel smoothly across the frame according to some "random" path. Can you help me with the `animateinline` environment?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, circle, fill=red] at (0, 0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75580/animate-line-path-using-tikz-and-animate-package?rq=1 help? If not, please explain what you've tried and where you are stuck.