# Tikz Figure Drawing Animation

Tags: beamer, animations

I would like to animate a diagram I made using Tikz by parts. Basically, I want the animation to

- draw first box/node then \pause
- display text in the box then \pause
- continuously draw an arrow then \pause
- draw second box then \pause
- write text, then arrow, and so on...

I tried to apply a solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75580/animate-line-path-using-tikz-and-animate-package) but I can't seem to make it work for a non-simultaneous case of multiple paths. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[minimum size=1cm]
    \node[draw,rectangle] (A)                       {A};
    \node[draw,rectangle] (B)   [right=of A]        {B};
    \node[draw,rectangle] (C)   [right=of B]        {C};
    \draw[->] (A.east) -- (B.west);
    \draw[->] (B.east) -- (C.west);     
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to TeX.SE! I suspect that this you like to use in some presentation. In this case you should use `beamer` document class which support uncovering part of text, images ...

Comment: Hi! I also tried using <+-> but I can't make it work with `multiframe` in the solution.

Comment: in your MWE is not used `beamer` nor`multiframe` etc. please show what you try so far ...

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[minimum size=1cm]
    \node<+->[draw,rectangle] (A) {\only<+->{A}};
    \node<+> (B) [right=of A] {};
    \node<+->[draw,rectangle] (B) [right=of A] {\only<+->{B}};
    \node<+> (C) [right=of B] {};
    \node<+->[draw,rectangle] (C) [right=of B] {\only<+->{C}};
    \draw<3->[->] (A.east) -- (B.west);
    \draw<6->[->] (B.east) -- (C.west); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ohhh I understand now how to apply `only` for the text. Is it possible to incorporate the multiframe solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75580/animate-line-path-using-tikz-and-animate-package) for drawing arrows?

Comment: @Park No idea about multiframe