# Cannot create animation in beamer with xelatex using the animate package

Tags: beamer, xetex, animations

I 'm not a TEX expert and I am trying to ceate some animations in a beamer presentation using the animate package.
Making the animations in a "normal" document (not a presentation) everything is fine.
When I try to put these animations into Beamer nothing happens. There is only the first frame(?) and nothing is working.
I use the XELATEX flavor of TEX.

For example, I can compile the code found in the second frame (answered by AlexG) in the page [Animating Protocols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6330/animating-protocols), with LATEX, but not with XELATEX.

Is there something I can do?

Thanks in advance.

Kostas.

Comment: No problem here with up-to-date TeXLive-2013 and MiKTeX-2.9. I ran `xelatex` on the code linked in your question.

Comment: which reader did you try? It works with Adobe Reader and PDF-XChange viewer but not with SumatraPDF or TeXworks viewer.

Comment: the only thing that was needed is just an update of the packages.
thank you very much,
Kostas.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue fixed by an update.