# Animation in beamer?

Tags: beamer

I was wondering if it is possible to make an animation in beamer. I normally work on graph theory. By a graph I mean a set of vertices and some edges joining them.

I wish to make an animation showing an isomorphism from one graph to the other. I could draw graphs using tikz package. But I don't know how to make the motion. So what I really want is to make an animation showing one point smoothly move to another point.

For example, I want something as below happen: [image]

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25394/1952, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6330/1952

Comment: You can also find some complete examples in Texample.net: http://texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/animations/. This one is not exactly an animation but similar http://texample.net/tikz/examples/prims-algorithm/

Comment: @Ignasi, thank your reference, but I don't want things moving with a pause, I want to have them moving smoothly.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75797/1952, shows previous examples but smoothly animated

Comment: @Ignasi, see my new edit.

Comment: Could you please edit your post and add a fully compilable example of the graph? It would be a fine starting point for the solvers even if the graph is static.

Comment: @Malipivo, unfortunately, I don't know how to make these graphs in latex, I used other software (for example, geogebra) to create it.

Comment: @Easy I see, I usually use TikZ+animate packages for similar tasks.

Comment: @Malipivo, can you provide some example and let me see the effect? Note that I don't want things appear one after one, I want object moving.

Comment: @Easy I'd love to, but I can't right now. Well, this might be of interest for you as a starting point, http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex2e/contrib/animate/animate.pdf

Comment: I've found this in geogebra forums: http://www.geogebra.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=25986

Answer (score 11):

I don't use `beamer` but one can start with that :

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,animate}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\xdef\C{8}
\xdef\H{4.5}

\begin{document}

\foreach \nxb in {0,.05,...,1,1,.95,...,0,0} {%
\begin{preview}
%\begin{animateinline}[controls]{10}
%   \multiframe{11}{nxb=0+.1}{%

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw (-1,-.5) rectangle (2*\H,2*\H-.5) ;

    \coordinate (C6) at (0,0) ;
    \coordinate (C4) at (\C,0) ;
    \coordinate (C1) at (0,\C) ;
    \coordinate (C3) at (\C,\C) ;
    \coordinate (C2) at ($(C1)!.5!(C3)$) ;
    \coordinate (C5) at ($(C6)!.5!(C4)$) ;
    \coordinate (C7) at ($(C6)!.5!(C3)$) ;

    \coordinate (H5) at ($(C1)!.5!(C4)$) ;
    \begin{scope}[shift=(H5)]
    \coordinate (H6) at (0:\H) ;
    \coordinate (H7) at (60:\H) ;
    \coordinate (H4) at (120:\H) ;
    \coordinate (H3) at (180:\H) ;
    \coordinate (H2) at (240:\H) ;
    \coordinate (H1) at (300:\H) ;
    \end{scope}

    \foreach \i in {1,...,7} {%
        \fill ($(H\i)!\nxb!(C\i)$) circle (2pt) coordinate (M\i) ; }
    \draw (M1)--(M2)--(M3)--(M4)--(M5)--(M6)--(M7)--(M4)
        (M6)--(M1)--(M5) ;

    \end{tikzpicture}
    %}
%\end{animateinline}
\end{preview}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: two things I am not sure. 1. How can you convert it to the gif file? When I compiled your codes I got a pdf file and it shows me the consecutive slides. 2. How do you embed this into beamer? Thanks

Comment: To made the animated gif you see an this page, I used a step of .01 instead of .05 and imported the pdf file in gimp as calques not as images with 300 ppp, then exported it as gif, et voilà. I don't use beamer at all, maybe I will soon, but now I can't help you with this.

Comment: @Easy: It's not possible to include animated gif files in beamer. You can include animations but not gif.